# How can I download all messages from a Google Groups?

Tags: google-groups

I would like to download all messages from a Google Groups because I want to analyze the discussion available in there. How can I do it?

E.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/thackday

Comment: in Google app script , it's not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download all messages from a Google group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522705/download-all-messages-from-a-google-group)

Answer (score 0):

Over a year after your post, someone else [asked a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522705/download-all-messages-from-a-google-group).  The OP used a screen scraper program/tool, but the selected answer was to use "... the gdata python library to get a list of all groups along with their respective URLs. From there I used selenium to scrape the groups for messages and all replies."