# How do I programmatically access Google Groups archives?

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-groups, google-groups-api

I want to get the text of recent Google Groups messages from a specific group in a Google Apps organization. The group is used for announcements, and I want to mirror this announcement text on a Python-powered website.

How can I get this text programmatically? I have found APIs for group settings, membership, and even inserting arbitrary messages for migration. But I can't find anything for getting text or html of recent messages.

Do I have to resort to HTML scraping?

Comment: Ya, if you want to get the html from messages, you'll have to use the mechanize framework.

Comment: That's very frustrating if true. I find it difficult to believe that nobody else has ever needed to parse Google Groups archives. It's a very obvious API that I think Google should be exposing.

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522705/download-all-messages-from-a-google-group)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download all messages from a Google group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522705/download-all-messages-from-a-google-group)