# Address List which emailed from

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups-api

I'm currently organizing the Google groups that our account has and would like to see where each group received the email.

As far as I'm looking at the public API, it seems that there is no way to know when a group received an email or how many it already received.
For example, if a member has been a member of a group since the beginning, it would be possible to create a list from the member's email archive, but I don't want to do that for each group.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Maybe one of the solutions is here, and I'll check it.
[Download all messages from a Google group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522705/download-all-messages-from-a-google-group)